# Flutter debugging not working on my phone, but works on every other phone in VSCODE

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-hotreload

The flutter hot restart/ reload doesn't work on my phone for all the flutter run, run with/without debugging. And the same works on all other phone very well.This issue of phone is not specific to any project, it is the same with all the projects.
[installing outputs image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VtBZ.png)

I have tried all the flutter run, run without debugging and start debugging in vscode connecting to my phone IQOO z6, I have developer option enabled, usb debugging enabled and also allowed my laptop to do debugging in my phone, but when i run flutter hot restart/reload it doesn't work when i press r. When i run with/without debugging it just says, installing build outputs and takes forever to run, and even my phone shows a black screen. Surprisingly, all of them work very well if i connect to another phone to my laptop from the same project.  Because of this, i have to run my app every single time i do any change. Please do tell me any solution that can work. Thank you in advance :)